# get String path of file in assets (kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to use a zip file in assets (myZip.zip) I tried many code but they didn't work "I need the String path of myZip.zip"

```
private val assetzip = "file:///android_asset/myZip.zip"
```

and

```
private val assetzip : String = applicationContext.assets.open("myZip.zip").toString()
```

Comment: What do you mean by zip file in the assets. Where is this zip file actually stored?

Comment: For what reason do you want to know its absolute path?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You say you need the string path of your zip file, but what do you need it for? Then we can know what part you actually need.

Comment: @RobCo  I want to extract zip file from assets to sdcard

Comment: Can't you just use an `InputStream` for this? `AssetManager#open`, and pair it with a `ZipInputStream`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the file path - use the `InputStream` returned from `AssetManager#open` with a `ZipInputStream`:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun unzip(am: AssetManager) {
    ZipInputStream(am.open("myZip.zip")).use { zis ->
        var ze: ZipEntry
        while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
            //etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that way but in my job i need Just String Address

Comment: Why do you need that? For what it's worth, I don't believe it's possible to get an absolute file path to Assets anyway (you may be able to find a hack that gets you the URI, but will probably break on different APIs and devices), but why do you want to use the file path instead of an InputStream?

Comment: I want to extract my zip file to external directory, I make FileHelper Class which get zip file from ExternalStorage and extract on External Storage I need a method to get access to raw or assets folder to use my FileHelper Class

Comment: So you can do something like `new File(assetPath)`? That's not going to work because **assets are not files**. They are stored inside the apk file, which is zipped. They are not part of the actual file system. Adjust your FileHelper class to take either an InputStream or an AssetManager + asset path